# Sentinel 2A L1C product convertion from TOA reflectance to BOA reflectance

Tags: atmospheric-correction, sentinel-2, reflectance

How can I convert the TOA reflectance values of L1C Sentinel2A products to **BOA (Bottom Of Atmosphere)** reflectance values?

Is there an equation?

Comment: [Sen2Cor](http://step.esa.int/main/third-party-plugins-2/sen2cor)

Comment: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dW8dY.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dW8dY.jpg) list index out of ranges is possible to resolve this problem

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. If you have a new question, please use [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Include all error message, SNAP version and Sen2Cor version

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/136133)

Answer (score 7):

You'll need to run ESA's Sen2Cor algorithm to process Sentinel-2 Level-1C data to Level-2A.

This will give you atmospherically corrected BOA data. If you then divide the values by the quantification value (10000) you'll end up with BOA reflectance data.

Download and install Sen2Cor: http://step.esa.int/main/third-party-plugins-2/sen2cor/

STEP help forum (useful info for Sen2cor): http://forum.step.esa.int/c/s2tbx